# unwanted vertical scrollbars

Tags: css, scrollbar

I have unwanted vertical scrollbars in all browsers even if the content does not occupy the entire page.
Improvement and changes to css are welcome!

```
 <div id="header">
 </div>
 <div id="container">
     <div id="title"><h2>Admin</h2></div>
     <div id="content">
         <div class="login">
             <div>&nbsp</div>
                 <form method="post" action="/admin/index.php">
                  <p><input type="text" name="username" value="" placeholder="Username"></p>
                  <p><input type="password" name="password" value="" placeholder="Password"></p>
                  <p><input type="submit" name="login" class="button" value="Send"></p>
                  <p class="error">&nbsp;</p>
                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Copyright &copy; 2010-2013</p>
</div>
```

this the css file

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #333399;
}

#header{
min-height:15%;
}

#container {
    min-height:80%;
 margin-left:auto;
     margin-right:auto;
     width:70%;
}

#footer {
text-align: center;
    min-height:5%;
}

#title{
    position:relative;
    background-color:#BAB3D6;
    padding:10px 0px 10px 10px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:3px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 10px;
     border-top-left-radius: 10px;
     border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

#content{
padding:5px 5px 5px 5px;
border:2px solid #BAB3D6;
position:relative;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
 }

.button{     
    background-color:#BAB3D6;
    border:0px; 
    display:inline-block;
    padding:6px 20px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #333399;
    cursor:pointer;    
 }

.button:hover {
    background-color:#0061a7;
    color: white;
 }

 .button:active {
    position:relative;
    top:1px;
}

.error{
    font-weight: bold;
    color:red;
}

form input[type="text"] {
    border: 2px solid #BAB3D6;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #333399;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
}

form input[type="password"] {
    border: 2px solid #BAB3D6;
    font-size: 85%;
    color: #333399;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px;
}

.login p {
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9a8/

====UPDATE=====

I have fix it with body height 99%

Comment: I'm not seeing the vertical scroll bar... I am on Safari.

Comment: safari is the only one I haven't texted :-)

Comment: I just posted an answer, let me know if it works. If it doesn't, just let me know and we can work from there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the minimum height out of your CSS elements. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gZ9a8/1/). And here is what you want to do to your CSS code:

```
     #container {
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        width:70%;
      }
```

This should fix any problem with that vertical scroll bar.

Comment: it whork but the problem in this case is footer come up, I use this layout for the entire site and see the footer in the middle of the pages is not the best ;)

Comment: Make sure that the div footer is the last thing in your HTML code before you end your <body> tags. Does that make sense?

Comment: Take the height percentage out for the footer as well.

Comment: yes because if the content don't fills the page the footer come up

Answer (score 0):

I saw the scroll bars, but only when I play with the window size. I think since you are using % for height, you can eliminate the `#container min-height:80%;` tag as this will eliminate the overflow/scrollbar issue.

When you use the header at 15% and the footer at 5% the remaining 80% is automatically filled with the container.

Another option could be to use the `position:relative` tag in the header and add a `top:15%;` to dial in the header positon. Or you could offer up a `min-height:10%;` and `max-height:15%;` to dial in the header size in total.

If you want the footer to always remain at the bottom, you can set `position:relative bottom:5%;` within it's css

Comment: the problem is not the header the problem is the footer if I eliminate #container min-height:80% footer come in the middle of the page if the content don't fills pages

Comment: no, the problem is that you are using minimum to declare your sizes. you are telling the page at the very least to use the full 100% of the size available. This leaves you no room for the resizing as needed. If you remove the `min` from your declarations you should be all set.

Comment: Ah ok I understand now but the problem with his fix is that  if the content don't fills the page the footer come up in the middle of the page I wont it on the bottom, I use this layou for the whole site

Answer (score 0):

```
simplest solution without editing ur css 


Remove height:100%; from body 


html, body {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 85%;
color: #333399;
}
```